# SQLite error code = 1

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I'm trying to insert some data into my SQLite database. But I keeo receiving an error code 1 saying that my column does not exist. Can someone help me please, Below is my code:

```
08-17 13:12:46.473: I/Database(13328): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = table login has no column named uid
08-17 13:12:46.503: E/Database(13328): Error inserting uid=502e7b90657ab1.86949026 created_at=2012-08-17 12:12:48 email=epaas name=hwheuu
08-17 13:12:46.503: E/Database(13328): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table login has no column named uid: , while compiling: INSERT INTO login(uid, created_at, email, name) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?);
08-17 13:12:46.503: E/Database(13328):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
08-17 13:12:46.503: E/Database(13328):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:92)
08-17 13:12:46.503: E/Database(13328):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:65)
08-17 13:12:46.503: E/Database(13328):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:83)
08-17 13:12:46.503: E/Database(13328):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:41)
08-17 13:12:46.503: E/Database(13328):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement(SQLiteDatabase.java:1231)
08-17 13:12:46.503: E/Database(13328):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1658)
08-17 13:12:46.503: E/Database(13328):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1515)
08-17 13:12:46.503: E/Database(13328):  at library.DatabaseHandler.addUser(DatabaseHandler.java:69)
08-17 13:12:46.503: E/Database(13328):  at com.thryfting.www.RegisterActivity$register.doInBackground(RegisterActivity.java:135)
08-17 13:12:46.503: E/Database(13328):  at com.thryfting.www.RegisterActivity$register.doInBackground(RegisterActivity.java:1)
08-17 13:12:46.503: E/Database(13328):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
08-17 13:12:46.503: E/Database(13328):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
08-17 13:12:46.503: E/Database(13328):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
08-17 13:12:46.503: E/Database(13328):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
08-17 13:12:46.503: E/Database(13328):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
08-17 13:12:46.503: E/Database(13328):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1027)
```

Below is my database code:

```
package library;

import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "thryfting_api";

    // Login table name
    private static final String TABLE_LOGIN = "login";

    // Login Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String KEY_UID = "uid";
    private static final String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LOGIN + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT UNIQUE,"
                + KEY_UID + " INTEGER,"
                + KEY_CREATED_AT + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LOGIN);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * Storing user details in database
     * */
    public void addUser(String name, String email, String uid, String created_at) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, name); // Name
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, email); // Email
        values.put(KEY_UID, uid); // Email
        values.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, created_at); // Created At

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_LOGIN, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    /**
     * Getting user data from database
     * */
    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){
        HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String,String>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // Move to first row
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
            user.put("name", cursor.getString(1));
            user.put("email", cursor.getString(2));
            user.put("uid", cursor.getString(3));
            user.put("created_at", cursor.getString(4));
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        // return user
        return user;
    }

    /**
     * Getting user login status
     * return true if rows are there in table
     * */
    public int getRowCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        int rowCount = cursor.getCount();
        db.close();
        cursor.close();

        // return row count
        return rowCount;
    }

    /**
     * Re crate database
     * Delete all tables and create them again
     * */
    public void resetTables(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        // Delete All Rows
        db.delete(TABLE_LOGIN, null, null);
        db.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Do a clear data from your app info or change the DATABASE_VERSION to 2 and check

Comment: Open your DB and check if the column actually exists.

Comment: when I do this I got same error but not success even I change database version =2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the error message

> table `login` has no column named `uid`

indicates that your database is not in the state you expect it. You do create that table with a column named `uid` (`KEY_UID`) but you have most likely added that column after the database was already created on your device. Once it is created it will persist until you explicitly delete that file or uninstall your app. And `onCreate` will not be executed again until the database file is missing.

What you need to do is to upgrade the database version each time you change the table definitions. That will trigger the `onUpgrade` code which will then recreate your table the way you defined it.

Your fix is most likely just

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
private static final String KEY_ID = "uid";
```

instead of

```
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
```

Comment: Error says `table login has no column named uid:` So he has already tried that, and has 2 columns. one UID and one ID